# After navigating to destination, start menu item is disabled

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a single activity class with 2 fragments, both at the top level of my navigation hierarchy.
Both fragments are connected to destinations, and they are shown in my navigation menu.

Other than the standard navigation menu, in `fragment1` I have a custom button associated to an action for navigating to `fragment2`, without arguments nor state to be remembered.

This works fine, including the standard back navigation to `fragment1` using the standard back functionality.

The problem is that after navigating using the custom button, the menu item  to `fragment1` is disabled. How can I restore it?

**Code managing navigation from custom button in `fragment1`:**

```
findNavController().navigate(HomeFragmentDirections.navFrag1toFrag2())
```

**NavigationGraph.xml**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
  android:label="@string/frag1"
  app:startDestination="@id/nav_frag1">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.perissf.Fragment1"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/navFrag1toFrag2"
            app:destination="@id/nav_frag2" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_frag2"
        android:name="com.perissf.Frag2"
        android:label="@string/frag2" />
</navigation>
```